# SystemError: Parent module 'setuptools' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm currently using google cloud platform ubuntu vminstance to run vscode.

Whenver I run `python3 __init__.py`, it will return this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from BatteryModel.batterymodel.conn.sqlDatabase import sqlDatabase
  File "/home/phuongdoanmr/sensa/SENSA_2020v1/BatteryModel/batterymodel/conn/sqlDatabase.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.db as db
  File "/home/phuongdoanmr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/home/phuongdoanmr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 6, in <module>
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "/home/phuongdoanmr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 82, in create_module
    return importlib.import_module('._distutils', 'setuptools')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 981, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 931, in _sanity_check
SystemError: Parent module 'setuptools' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Could anyone please suggest a way to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be the issue here, but `python __init__.py` doesn’t make sense: such a file should be run via `python -m` (and should really be a `__main__.py` instead).

Comment: @AdolfoOG oh hey it works for me, thank you so much

Comment: @DavisHerring hi Davis, it seems that using python3 __init__.py doesn't cause any error. Thank you for your entry.

Comment: @VioletEvergarden: I didn’t say it caused an error; I said it was usually/conceptually wrong.

Comment: I understand, I genuinely thanked you duhhh